# Something very strange in ListView jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

if i write this:

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="PIC/999.jpeg">
                    <h2>Google Chrome</h2>
                    <p>Google Chrome is a free, open-source web browser. Released in 2008.</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#">Some Text</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="PIC/999.jpeg">
                    <h2>Mozilla Firefox</h2>
                    <p>Firefox is a web browser from Mozilla. Released in 2004.</p>
                </a>
                <a href="#">Some Text</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

i see Beautiful Design

[image]

**but i need for my Mobile web this:**

```
<script>
        function XX() {

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "1.xml", false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

            $("#ZIBI").empty();

            var ALL;
            var ID,Fname, Lname, Phone,Car;

            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("men");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                try{ID = x[i].getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { ID = "0";}
                try{Fname = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Fname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { Fname = "0"; }
                try{Lname = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Lname")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { Lname = "0"; }
                try{Phone = x[i].getElementsByTagName("S_phone")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;}
                catch (err) { Phone = "0"; }
                try { Car = x[i].getElementsByTagName("car")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue; }
                catch (err) { Car = "0"; }
                ALL = 
                      '<li>' +
                      '<a href="#">' +
                      '<img src="PIC/' + ID + '.jpeg">' +
                      '<p class="nam">' + Fname + " " + Lname + '</p>' +
                      //'<p class="des">' + Lname + '</p>' +
                      '<p class="phn">' + Phone + '</p>' +
                      '<p class="crr">' + Car + '</p>' +
                      '<hr>' +
                      '</a>' +
                      '</li>' 

                $("#ZIBI").append(ALL);
            }
        }
    </script>


 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="ZIBI" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" ></ul>
```

and i see this Ugly design

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the jqueryMobile docs:

Updating lists:

If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the `refresh()` method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

Comment: thanks its works !! , what i need to add to my code that every press on any cell in the listView i can call the number ?

Comment: try using the tel: attribute in the link. http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/docs/pages/link-formats.html